# Using nginx to host tor hidden service through unix socket

Tags: sockets, nginx, tor

I am on ubuntu 20.04 hosting a tor hidden service using nginx.

I currently have it working using port 8080 in the following configuration:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
    {
    return 405;
    }
    root /var/www/example;
    server_name example.onion>
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

/etc/tor/torrc

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/example/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
```

That's great and all, but it would be my preference to accomplish this using unix sockets. To that end I have tried the following configuration:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen unix:/run/tor/nginx-onion-80.sock;
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ )
    {
    return 405;
    }
    root /var/www/example;
    server_name example.onion>
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

/etc/tor/torrc

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/example/
HiddenServicePort 80 unix:/run/tor/nginx-onion-80.sock
```

This configuration does not work. By this I mean that the hidden service is unreachable on the tor network. There are no errors generated in either the tor log file or nginx log file. Both are running happily, just not producing the desired results.

I used socat to pass GET / HTTP:/1.1 to the socket and confirmed in the nginx log file that nginx was successful in 'listening'. So it would appear nginx is working just fine.

I had a look in the tor log file, however, it doesn't seem to provide any information on whether it was successful in opening the socket. That said, I know tor is generally working because it works using TCP port 8080.

I thought this might be a permissions issue with the .sock file. As a quick check I modified the permissions of the socket file as follows:

```
sudo chmod 777 /run/tor/nginx-onion-80.sock
chown debian-tor:debian-tor /run/tor/nginx-onion-80.sock
```

This did not work either.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: What `nginx -t` command says?

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. How did you solve it? Tor logs don't complain/report anything wrong, but, like you, I suspect it is Tor and not NginX. Can't seem to figure it out what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue. Unfortunately, it doesn't work if you change the owner of the sock file later after starting nginx.

Try starting tor as root:

```
root@server:~# tor
```

Note: do not start tor with the systemctl command. Although you could overwrite the system service with which user to start tor.